# Can I replace DDR3 SDRAM with DDR3 SODIMM?

Tags: memory

I am buying 4 desktops and want to upgrade the RAM immediately.

Is there much difference between SDRAM and SODIMM RAM?  From what I gather, the two types have different widths because one is normally used in laptops and the other in desktops, however will it still function as normal on a Desktop?

I am getting an [Acer Aspire XC-215](http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/model/DT.SXDEK.002)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between DDR3 SDRAM and DDR3 SODIMM for laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/660840/difference-between-ddr3-sdram-and-ddr3-sodimm-for-laptop)

Comment: That duplicate doesn't explicitly say that they wont work

Comment: Patrick, yes, good spot. However, you need to [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/934504/edit), explain you've read that post and why it doesn't answer your question. This will ensure your post doens't get closed :)

Comment: As suggested, I've removed my answer as an answer because it merely answers the question. Instead I'll just comment that the two standards are incompatible with each other. They just don't fit!

Comment: Look up 'SODIMM to DIMM Adapter'. Get some of those.

Answer (score 0):

As you said the visible difference is the size. SODIMM is made for laptop/Notebook and SDRAM for desktop. Your PC Acer Aspire XC-215 comes with a SDRAM slot and hence you cant insert a SODIMM RAM module into it. Some of the desktop PC's use SODIMM modules also, say for example Apple Mac mini.

For [reference](http://www.simmtester.com/page/news/showpubnews.asp?num=168) [DDR3 SDRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM)